# How to change fb:registration tag visibility from inside getLoginStatus() function

Tags: plugins, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration, facebook-login

This is how I've set up my login/registration flow. On the index.html page there is a link. Once it is clicked you are sent to a second page where your login status is checked and the fb login/registration box is shown if you're not registered or logged in. 
What I've done is made the tag invisible on the page until after the login status is checked? Once it's checked I want it to become visible if the user isn't logged in or registered, but it's not becoming visible. 
What is the best way to hide the visibility of the register/login box until login status is checked. I don't want to use facebooks login() function because I don't want a pop up window. I want to use the XFBML tag. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script >
  <base href="http://spilot.koding.com/">


  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>


  // Additional JS functions here
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '3967205****88', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//http://spilot.koding.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    // get login status

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // not_authorized


        document.getElementByName("login").style.visibility = visible;

  } else {
    // not_logged_in

      document.getElementByName("login").style.visibility = visible;

  }
 });
  };



  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));



</script>


<div id="fb-root" name="login" style="visibility:hidden">
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=396720557089188&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration 
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
  redirect-uri="http://spilot.koding.com/signedRequest.php" width="530">
</fb:registration> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your closing tag for `fb-root`. Also why not wrap another div around the `fb:registration` tag and show/hide that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that worked for me. I decided to use the registration plugin instead. I put the iframe in a div and set the div's visibility to "hidden", then in the init code where it checks log in status, I call a function that uses document.getElementById().style.visibility ="visible" to grab the div and change its visibility. Make sure everything that needs quotes around it has them, that was one of my original mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script >
  <base href="http://spilot.koding.com/">


  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>


  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '396720557******', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//http://spilot.koding.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // not_authorized
    ///log function will change div visibility to "visible"
   log();

  } else {
    // not_logged_in
   log();

  }
 });//closes fb.getLoginStatus
  };// closes fbAsyncInit


  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  //change div visibility to visible

  var log = function(){
     document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = "visible";


  }//closes function log()
</script>

//put iframe inside a div and set the div's visibility to hidden. 

<div id ="login" style = "visibility:hidden" >
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=396720557089188&&
             redirect_uri=http://spilot.koding.com/signedRequest.php&
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
 </iframe>

    </div>





</body>
</html>
```